# rearranging an array of arrays (python)

Tags: python, arrays, repeat, python-itertools

So I have a array of arrays, like

```
[array([-0.05504106,  4.21890792]), array([-0.05504106,  4.21890792]), array([-0.0533802 ,  4.10717668]), array([-0.0546635 ,  4.19501313])]
```

And what I'm attempting to do is make it into an array of 2 arrays, in which the components are put together like this:

```
[array([-0.05504106, -0.05504106, -.0533802, -.0546635]), array([4.21890792, 4.21890792, 4.10717668, 4.19501313])
```

I've tried a number of approaches. The first is as follows:

```
for i in range(len(array_1)-1):
zipped = zip(array_1[i], array_1[i+1], array_1[i+2])
print zipped
```

However, this approach has the drawback of having to add an `array_1[i+n]` for each additional array within `array_1`. Not at all practical if `array_1` has many arrays within it.

The next thing I tried was attempting to use `itertools.repeat` in conjunction with the above code, like so:

```
for i in range(len(array_1)-1):
zipped = zip(itertools.repeat(array_1[i], len(array_1))
print zipped
```

however, this did not function the way I wanted it to.

Could you give me some idea of how I would accomplish this task? Should I be using `zip` and/or `intertools.repeat`?

Comment: so you want them to be grouped by their inner-index? basically: `[(array[0][0], array[1][0], ..., array[n][0]), (array[0][1], ..., array[n][1]), ..., (array[0][m], ..., array[n][m])]` ?

Comment: yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which `array` class you are using, but with simple lists you can use zip:

```
a = [[-0.05504106, 4.21890792], [-0.05504106, 4.21890792], [-0.0533802, 4.10717668],[-0.0546635, 4.19501313]]

b = list(zip(*a)) #omit list in python2
print(b)
```

This prints:

```
[(-0.05504106, -0.05504106, -0.0533802, -0.0546635), (4.21890792, 4.21890792, 4.10717668, 4.19501313)]
```

Comment: huh. well, thats alot easier than i thought it would be. I guess im not familiar enough with the use of the zip() function. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipR. As a rule of thumb: `zip(*x)` unzips `x`.